# Class & View for displaying Max & Avg values for each day in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am extremely new to python (and django) and I've searched but honestly I'm not sure if I'm searching for the right stuff so decided to ask for some help.

Here is my class. I have a script setup to enter and save these values every 5 minutes into the db.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    class Meta:
            ordering = ['time']
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    inside = models.FloatField()
    outside = models.FloatField()
    gavg = models.IntegerField()
    ghigh = models.IntegerField()
```

I am wanting to setup a class/view to display the date obviously, the average(and high) for 'inside' & 'outside' for that day. The average of gavg for that day. The high for 'ghigh' that day. And this would need to be done for every single day from the Entry class.

I've tried to understand what I need to do in ORM but had issues with timezone aware datetime. I'm guessing I need another class, and I've seen some functions out there that might do what I need but I am having a difficulty time visualizing how the class should be defined and how/where the average/high functions should go. Or would this be better suited as an SQL query?

Comment: did you use same model to find `gavg` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the aggregated result as below,

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max

aggrate_result = Entry.objects.filter(time=filter_date).aggregate(avg_inside=Avg('inside'), avg_outside=Avg('outside'),
                                                                  max_inside=Max('inside'), max_outside=Max('outside'))
```

You should read the [official documentaion of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/) for more details regaurding `Aggregation`.

In your view, you could display the aggregated response as below,

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db.models import Avg, Max


def my_sample_view(request):
    aggrate_result = Entry.objects.filter(time=filter_date).aggregate(avg_inside=Avg('inside'), avg_outside=Avg('outside'),
                                                                      max_inside=Max('inside'), max_outside=Max('outside'))
    return JsonResponse(aggrate_result)
```

Note: You should go through the [official doc](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to get familier with the stuffs. Happy learning ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), you can run a schedule which will update all the objects in database per day.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

def update_previous_day_entires():
    current_day = timezone.now()
    previous_day = current_day - timedelta(hours=24)
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(time__gt=previous_day,time__lt=current_day)

    # Calculate average and high here

    Entry.objects.filter(time__gt=previous_day,time__lt=current_day).update(
    gavg=avg,ghigh=high)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you guys. I used a combination of both to obtain what I needed.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Avg, Max
from temp.models import *
import temp.views
import django

def update_avg(self, start, end):
    entries_for_period = Entry.objects.filter(time__gte=start, time__lte=end)
    avg_values = ['inside', 'outside', 'gavg']
    average_value = entries_for_period.aggregate(*[Avg(x) for x in avg_values])
    return {x:average_value['%s__avg' % x] for x in avg_values}



def update_high(self, start, end):
    entries_for_period2 = Entry.objects.filter(time__gte=start, time__lte=end)
    high_values = ['inside', 'outside', 'ghigh']
    high_value = entries_for_period2.aggregate(*[Max(x) for x in high_values])
    return {x:high_value['%s__max' % x] for x in high_values}

current_day = timezone.now()    
previous_day = current_day - timedelta(hours=24)
date_entry = previous_day.date()

avg_choice = update_avg(date_entry,previous_day,current_day)
high_choice = update_high(date_entry,previous_day,current_day)

history = History(date=date_entry, avginside=round(avg_choice['inside'],2),highinside=round(high_choice['inside'],2),avgoutside=round(avg_choice['outside'],2),highoutside=high_choice['outside'],avgg=avg_choice['gavg'],highg=high_choice['ghigh'],starttime=previous_day,endtime=current_day)
history.save()
```

Now I can get a daily snapshot of the average and high values of my model's input. Thanks!